# All K such that if $|\int_E f d\mu|<K$ for all measurable E then $||f||_1<1$

Tags: real-analysis

I am working through a practice packet and I have come across one I have no idea how to approach. I need to find all constants $K>0$ for which: If $(X,M,\mu)$ is any positive measure space and if $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is any integrable function s.t. $|\int_E f d\mu|<K$ for all $E\in M$ then $||f||_1<1.$ I appreciate any hints/solutions you have to offer.

Comment: HINT: Try to consider only positive function in order to avoid the use of the absolute value. Secondly, recall that in a measure space $(X,M, \mu)$ you have that $X \in M$. Conclude that $K$ must be $\le 1$.

Comment: You can show that $K \leq 1/2$ is sufficient using the fact that if $f$ is measurable then $\{x : f(x) \geq 0\}$ is also measurable.

Comment: I think you can show $K\leq 1/2$ is necessary if the space as the property that there exists a set with positive and finite measure such that it can be divided into two disjiont sets with almost equal measure.

Comment: The difficulty is weird spaces, like spaces that consist of just one element $x$ with measure $c$.  Then $\int f = f(x)c$ and $\int |f| = |f(x)|c$, so we can have $K=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear to me if you first define the measure space, and then find all such $K$, or if $K$ also includes consideration of all measure spaces.  In the latter case, $K\leq 1/2$ is both necessary and sufficient:

-Sufficiency of $K\leq 1/2$:  Same as my comment above (just use the fact that if $f$ is measurable then $\{x: f(x)\geq 0\}$ and $\{x : f(x) < 0\}$ are both measureable).

-Necessity of $K \leq 1/2$:  Suppose $K>1/2$.  Consider the usual measure on the real number line.  Define $f(x)$ in a nice way to have support only on $[0,1]$ (so $f(x)=0$ if $x \notin [0,1]$). Your construction of $f$ should make it satisfy the condition $|\int_E f(x)dx| < K$ for all measurable sets $E$, but be such that $\int_0^1 |f(x)|dx\geq 1$.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply. Thanks for the help it was very useful.